# Excel VB use a column's cell values as variable for web scraper

Tags: excel, vba

I am aware it is possible to use VB in Excel to scrape a webpage with the below:

```
Sub ImportAnalystEst()
Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement    As IHTMLElement

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument


With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates", False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


For Each oElement In oHtml.getElementsByClassName("snapshot")
  wsTarget.Range("A" & i) = Split(oHtml.getElementsByClassName("snapshot").Item(0).FirstChild.FirstChild.innerHTML, "TD")(7)
  wsTarget.Range("A" & i) = Replace(wsTarget.Range("A" & i), ">", "")
  wsTarget.Range("A" & i) = Replace(wsTarget.Range("A" & i), "</", "")
  i = i + 1
Next


End Sub
```

But I need to iterate over several webpages. To do that, I have column A in my worksheet set up with each row representing a value to be used in the URL in place of the stock as seen here:

```
http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/*VARIABLE REPRESENTING COLUMN SHEET2:A:A*/analystestimates
```

But I don't know how to pull in and loop through each row to scrape each URL, adding the new output below the output from the previous URL.

I assume it has something to do with this:

```
Dim Rng2 As Range
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set Rng2 = Range("A:A")
```

But I am lost from there. I want to output the result in column B of the same row of the url variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want data from snapshot table on each page, that each page has the same structure, and that there are no gaps in the symbols range in column A.....

1. Read the symbols into an array by determining the last populated row in col A
2. Loop that array and substitute the "placeholder" text in the url with the current symbol to use in your WinHttp request
3. Have a correctly sized array to hold the results and update each row of that array as you process a new url. As the `results` array is passed `ByRef`, and is correctly dimensioned in advance, you can use the loop variable `i` to target the correct row to update. A helper sub, `UpdateResults`, is used to manage this process. Rows of the webpage table are converted into columns so you have a 1:1 ratio for symbol to row count for target webpage in loop.
4. Develop error-handling as you deem appropriate. Current error handling just assures that all retrieved results, up to point of error, are written out. They are written starting from column B to ensure no input data (symbols) are lost.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportAnalystEst()

    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, symbols() As Variant, url As String
    
    url = "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/placeholder/analystestimates"
    Set htmlDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, results() As Variant
    
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = GetLastRow(targetSheet) 'find last row in symbols column
    symbols = targetSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value 'read symbols in from column A
    
    Dim headers() As Variant, i As Long
    
    headers = Array("Symbol", "Average Recommendation", "Average Target Price", "Number Of Ratings", "FY Report Date", "Last Quarter's Earnings", _
                    "Year Ago Earnings", "Current Quarter's Estimate", "Current Year's Estimate", "Median PE on CY Estimate", _
                    "Next Fiscal Year Estimate", "Median PE on Next FY Estimate")
    
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(symbols, 1), 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    
    On Error GoTo errhand: 'TODO You might further develop this to handle retries etc based on http errors. Current set-up will write out progress to sheet
    
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    
        For i = LBound(symbols, 1) To UBound(symbols, 1) 'loop over symbols read in from col A of sheet stored in array symbols
        
            .Open "GET", Replace$(url, "placeholder", symbols(i, 1)), False 'update the url with the current symbol
            
            .send
            
            htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            
            results(i, 1) = symbols(i, 1)
            
            UpdateResults i, results, htmlDoc
            
        Next
    End With
  
errhand:
 
    With wsTarget
        .Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, UBound(headers, 1) + 1) = headers 'place to right of symbols to avoid overwriting in case of failures
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(LBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateResults(ByVal i As Long, ByRef results() As Variant, ByVal htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
    'grab snaphot table and empty rows into columns of single row in results array
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, r As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow, c As Long
    
    Set table = htmlDoc.querySelector(".table.value-pairs")
    c = 2
    
    For Each r In table.Rows
        results(i, c) = r.Children(1).innerText
        c = c + 1
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    'Find last populated row for a given column (optional)/ worksheet
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
.Open "GET", "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates", False
to
.Open "GET", myUrl.Value, False

Then before With CreateObject("WINHTTP... add line:
For each myUrl in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
or
For each myUrl in Sheets("Sheet1").Usedrange. Column(1)

Before end sub :next myUrl

But results will be on Sheet1 in the same range. You should change output sheet or/and range in the place

Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

You can remove it with:
worksheets.add
Set wsTarget = ActiveSheet